# flatMapValues (whole_list,an element list)

Tags: pyspark, rdd, flatmap

i have an rdd with keys to be integers. For each key i have a list of strings. Example: `[(0, ['transworld', 'systems', 'inc', 'trying', 'collect', 'debt', 'mine', 'owed', 'inaccurate'])]`

What i want is to get a new RDD like this:

```
[(0, ['transworld', 'systems', 'inc', 'trying', 'collect', 'debt', 'mine', 'owed', 'inaccurate'],'transworld')]
[(0, ['transworld', 'systems', 'inc', 'trying', 'collect', 'debt', 'mine', 'owed', 'inaccurate'],'systems')]
[(0, ['transworld', 'systems', 'inc', 'trying', 'collect', 'debt', 'mine', 'owed', 'inaccurate'],'inc')] etc
```

I think tha i need flatMapValues but can't find the way to use it. Anybody help?

Comment: flatMap is the way to go: `rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [ x + (e,) for e in x[1] ]).collect()`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is useful -

> 1. Not sure about the usecase 2. Written in scala

```scala
  val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((0, Seq("transworld", "systems", "inc", "trying", "collect", "debt",
      "mine",
    "owed", "inaccurate"))))
    rdd.flatMap{case (i, seq) => Seq.fill(seq.length)((i, seq)).zip(seq).map(x => (x._1._1, x._1._2, x._2))}
      .foreach(println)

    /**
      * (0,List(transworld, systems, inc, trying, collect, debt, mine, owed, inaccurate),transworld)
      * (0,List(transworld, systems, inc, trying, collect, debt, mine, owed, inaccurate),systems)
      * (0,List(transworld, systems, inc, trying, collect, debt, mine, owed, inaccurate),inc)
      * (0,List(transworld, systems, inc, trying, collect, debt, mine, owed, inaccurate),trying)
      * (0,List(transworld, systems, inc, trying, collect, debt, mine, owed, inaccurate),collect)
      * (0,List(transworld, systems, inc, trying, collect, debt, mine, owed, inaccurate),debt)
      * (0,List(transworld, systems, inc, trying, collect, debt, mine, owed, inaccurate),mine)
      * (0,List(transworld, systems, inc, trying, collect, debt, mine, owed, inaccurate),owed)
      * (0,List(transworld, systems, inc, trying, collect, debt, mine, owed, inaccurate),inaccurate)
      */
```